# Should questions purely about online versions of a game be allowed?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Here's one example: [Are there any English servers where I can play Mahjong online?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/152/where-can-i-play-mahjong-online)

Comment: Good question. I have doubt about the opposite too. Should be allowed to ask about board games based or similar to an on-line or computer game?

Comment: @bigown: if you feel that's an important question, it might be better to ask it separately.

Comment: I will wait some answers about your question first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion, if the online version of the boardgame is still really like the boardgame then it should be OK.

So the question:"Where can I play boardgame x online?" is valid IMHO. But questions about the scoring system used in the online version are off.

At least, that's what I think is best.

Comment: Agreed. For example, in the mahjong case, the mahjong solitaire that is a popular computer game is off-topic, as it's pretty much only played on a computer. The mahjong multi-player gambling game is on-topic, as it is a valid board game (card game? tile game?) and asking about venues for playing online doesn't fundamentally change that.

Comment: @BrianCampbell Please see the related discussion at [meta.gaming](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1348/does-this-site-support-the-computerized-versions-of-board-games/1350#1350).

Answer (score 3):

Um, well, I think something like [VASL](http://www.vasl.org/) would be on-topic for anything but a tech question (`belongs-on-superuser`) but anything you couldn't resolve manually is firmly off-topic.

Comment: Questions that can't be answered manually are probably `belongs-on-gaming`, actually.

Answer (score 3):

Since I created both the question and the [Mahjong proposal at Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22488/mahjong), I'd like to add a few remarks.

The Gaming.SE site it about computer games, mahjong behaves more similar to card games than to the games there. Also, I am going to ask many other questions about Mahjong itself (having nothing to do with playing  online).

The proposal was closed because it is "a subset of Board and Card games". So either the question should be allowed on this site, or the proposal should be reopened. I personally believe that the proposal was closed rightfully, because this site can provide a home for Mahjong.

Comment: I definitely think that Mahjong questions are on-topic. It's the online aspect that's questionable. That's also what this meta-question is about.

Comment: I agree, Mahjong questions belong here.  But "Why does XYZ Mahjong client always ask me to log in when I connect?" probably does not.

Answer (score 2):

It's a tricky one, as the expertise here is naturally online-savvy and slanted towards board games, but I'd say **no**, not when it is purely about the online version. It's better suited to [gaming.stackexchange.com](http://gaming.stackexchange.com).

The clue is in the title of the site - '**Board** and Card Games' ;)

I toyed with reposting my '[Is there an iPhone/smartphone version of Diplomacy?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1986/is-there-an-iphone-smartphone-version-of-diplomacy)' question from gaming.stackexchange.com, but if we allowed those types of question we'd open the flood gates to all kinds of 'I like X, where is it online' questions and a lot of overlap with gaming.stackexchange.com.

To put it another way, of the two sites, where would you ask 'I like Half Life 2, what board games would i also like?' - probably not gaming.stackexchange.com.

Comment: especially now that gaming does not allow game-rec questions! :)