# Questions about a board game that was ported to a video game

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I recently bought Elder Signs: Omens on my iPhone and I wanted to ask questions about it. I've never played the actual board game equivalent, so I don't know if the digital version is as similar to the original as say Catan on my iPad (which is almost exactly like the original).

My question is, should any questions about a game like this be asked here or on [gaming.se](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, questions are fine about that game here.

I believe everything talked about in this previous question still applies: 
[Should questions purely about online versions of a game be allowed?](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/should-questions-purely-about-online-versions-of-a-game-be-allowed)

In short, if your questions are about the game, they are on-topic.  If your questions are about technical issues (The game crashes, or won't start) then they should be directed elsewhere as we do not have the expertise here to answer.

Thanks!